# jQuery .html not working on table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't work out why in the ajax success callback the '.html()' is not working. The intention is to replace the '' contents. The classes are being added to the element but the contents of it are blank:

```
<td class="book-class centre cancelled"></td>
```

I've removed all other scripts from the page to ensure nothing is clashing, I've tried removing the .removeClass() and .addClass() but still it's not working. After spending two hours staring at it I'm sure this is going to end up being something simple but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Cancel Class
    $(document).on('click', '.cancel-class', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var cell = this;
      var row = $(this).parent();
      var id = $(row).data('booking-id');

      $(this).html('<img src="assets/images/spinner.gif" class="spinner" data-booking-id="'+id+'">');

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "controllers/cancelClass.ctrl.php",
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         data: {"id": id},

         success: function() {

            // NOT WORKING
            $(cell).removeClass().addClass('book-class centre cancelled').html('<i class="fa fa-times-circle></i> Cancelled'); 
         },

         error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      });

   });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's just a typo in the question, but if not this would surely be an issue. In the following line:

```
$(cell).removeClass().addClass('book-class centre cancelled').html('<i class="fa fa-times-circle></i> Cancelled');
```

You've forgotten a closing double quotation.  It should be this:

```
$(cell).removeClass().addClass('book-class centre cancelled').html('<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancelled');
```